# get name and package of calling function

Tags: go

I need to know the name of the go-package and function (including the receiver name) of the calling function.

This is my current code:

```
func retrieveCallInfo() {
    pc, _, _, _ := runtime.Caller(1)

    funcName := runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name()
    lastDot := strings.LastIndexByte(funcName, '.')

    fmt.Printf("  Package: %s\n", funcName[:lastDot])
    fmt.Printf("  Func:   %s\n", funcName[lastDot+1:])
}
```

However, the code doesn't behave exactly as it should.

```
// When called from a conventional (free) function:
runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name() // returns <package-path>.<funcName>

// When called from a method receiver function:
runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name() // returns <package-path>.<receiverName>.<funcName>
```

When called from a receiver function, the receiver name is part of the package name, rather than the function name - which is not what I want.

Here's a demonstration: https://play.golang.org/p/-99sZXr4ptD

In the second example, I want the package name to be `main` and the function name to be `empty.f`.
Since dots are also valid parts of a package name, I can't simply split at another dot - maybe it's actually not the receiver, but part of the package name.

Hence, the information returned by `runtime.FuncForPC()` is ambiguous and not enough.

How can I get the correct results?

Comment: @Flimzy I edited the question to clarify the problem (`FuncForPC()` returns ambiguous data)

Comment: Thank you for the edit. It's more clear what you want now.  Although I don't think it's ambiguous at all. It seems pretty clear exactly which function it's referring to. I think you'll just have to do your own parsing, much as you already are. But rather than parsing based on the last dot, do it on the first.

Comment: If package `x/y` contains a struct `z`, which has a function called `f`, then the result will be `x/y.z.f`. I can easily parse that.
However, if the package "x/y.z" contains a function called `f` (note that the dot is part of the package name), the result will also be `x/y.z.f`, and I can't distinguish between those two cases.

Comment: @maja: How do you have a package named `x/y.z`? `y.z` is not a valid package [identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#identifier)

Comment: Okay, somehow i tought that since package import paths can contain dots ("github.com/foo/bar"), package names themself can also contain dots (which - of course - makes no sense). And if a project folder contains a dot, the package name must be different than the folder name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The results are correct. You'll need to do some parsing to format the results the way you want them; for example, try splitting on dots *after the last slash* in the string:

```
pc, _, _, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
funcName := runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name()
lastSlash := strings.LastIndexByte(funcName, '/')
if lastSlash < 0 {
    lastSlash = 0
}
lastDot := strings.LastIndexByte(funcName[lastSlash:], '.') + lastSlash

fmt.Printf("Package: %s\n", funcName[:lastDot])
fmt.Printf("Func:   %s\n", funcName[lastDot+1:])
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/-Nbos0a1Ifp